# Toggle .active class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to toggle the class `.active` with jquery, heres what I've got so far:

**html**

```
<div class="downloadButtons">
            <div class="download-button-wrapper">
                    <div id="dd" class="desktopBackground downloadFontIcons" tabindex="1">DESKTOP
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">2560 x 1440</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">1800 x 900</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="download-button-wrapper">
                    <div id="de" class="tabletBackground downloadFontIcons" tabindex="1">PHONE
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">640 x 960</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">1136 x 640</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">720 x 1280</a></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>  


            <div class="download-button-wrapper">
                    <div id="df" class="phoneBackground downloadFontIcons" tabindex="1">TABLET
                        <ul class="dropdown">
                            <li><a href="#">2560 x 1600</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">2048 x 1536</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
            </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>
```

**css**

```
.downloadButtons{
    display: block;
    width: 780px;
    height: 200px;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

/* GLOBALS - Dropdowns*/
.downloadFontIcons{
    /* Size and position */
    position: relative; /* Enable absolute positionning for children and pseudo elements */
    width: 184px;
    height: 44px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 44px;
    margin-right: 68px;
    font-size: .7em;
    color: #9ea7b3;
    background-color: #F9FAFC;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none;
    border: 1px solid #eaedf1;
}   
.downloadFontIcons .dropdown{
    /* Size & position */
    position: absolute;
    top: 110%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;

    /* Styles */
    background: white;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    list-style: none;

    /* Hiding */
    opacity: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
}

::selection {
    background: transparent; 
}

::-moz-selection {
    background: transparent; 
}

.download-button-wrapper {
    *zoom: 1;
    float: left;
}

.downloadFontIcons  .dropdown li a {
    display: block;
    height: 44px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #9ea7b3;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition-delay: 0s;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}


/* Hover state */
.downloadFontIcons .dropdown li:hover a {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color:#FF562A;
}

/* Active state */

.downloadFontIcons.active .dropdown {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

/* No CSS3 support */

.no-opacity       .downloadFontIcons .dropdown,
.no-pointerevents .downloadFontIcons .dropdown {
    display: none;
    opacity: 1; /* If opacity support but no pointer-events support */
    pointer-events: auto; /* If pointer-events support but no pointer-events support */
}

.no-opacity       .downloadFontIcons.active .dropdown,
.no-pointerevents .downloadFontIcons.active .dropdown {
    display: block;
}
```

**js**

```
       function DropDown(el) {
                this.dd = el;
                this.initEvents();
            }
            DropDown.prototype = {
                initEvents : function() {
                    var obj = this;

                    obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
                        $(this).toggleClass('active');
                        event.stopPropagation();
                    }); 
                }
            }

            $(function() {

                var dd = new DropDown( $('#dd') );

                $(document).click(function() {
                    // all dropdowns
                    $('.wrapper-dropdown-2').removeClass('active');
                });

            });



            $(function() {

                var de = new DropDown( $('#de') );

                $(document).click(function() {
                    // all dropdowns
                    $('.wrapper-dropdown-2').removeClass('active');
                });

            });

            $(function() {

                var df = new DropDown( $('#df') );

                $(document).click(function() {
                    // all dropdowns
                    $('.wrapper-dropdown-2').removeClass('active');
                });

            });
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UhSqd/)

I need to toggle the active state of the buttons, for example as I click on the `desktop` button the dropdown list appears, then when I click on the `phone` button, I want the `desktop` list to disappear. I think the changes needed to be on this part of the code as with this code I think I'm only targeting `dd` elements:

```
function DropDown(el) {
  this.dd = el;
  this.initEvents();
}
DropDown.prototype = {
  initEvents : function() {
    var obj = this;

    obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
      $(this).toggleClass('active');
      event.stopPropagation();
    });
  }
}
```

I have very little knowledge of javascript so not sure what do to. Need your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your `initEvents` function you can look for and remove all active classes on your buttons excluding the clicked button.  That should give you the functionality your looking for.

```
initEvents : function() {
  var obj = this;

  obj.dd.on('click', function(event){
    $('.active').not($(this)).removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/UhSqd/1/

Comment: perfect!! was missing the removeClass. thanks a lot!