# Displaying text when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is inside my CSS:

```
div.hide { 
     display:none; 
     }
div.show {
     color: #66CCFF;
     }
```

This is in my HTML:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/#16:10">16:10</a>

<script language="JavaScript">
    function showText(show,hide)
    {
        document.getElementById(show).className = "show";
        document.getElementById(hide).className = "hide";
    }
</script>

<a name="16:10" onclick="showText('text1')" href="javascript:void(0);"></a>
<div id="text1" class="hide">This is your monitors aspect ratio.</div>
```

I'm trying to make the first link display the "This is your monitors aspect ratio." text lower on the page.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: this might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20590181/toggle-active-class-with-jquery

Comment: I'm confused by your question and your comments to the  given answers... can you be more precise on what link you're actually clicking? And why you use `http://www.website.com/#16:10` instead of only `#16:10` And do you know that the `name` attribute for anchors is deprecated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pure CSS Answer

Ok, if you just want to append text after you have moved to a position in a page using an `anchor` tag, you *could* do it with nothing but CSS similar to the following:

```
 a:target:after{
    content: " Test";
    background-color: #ccffcc;
 }
```

What this does is appends the text "Test" after the active anchor and colors. Here is an example page with implementation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Link Printer 2</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <style>
         a:target:after{
            content: " Test";
            background-color: #ccffcc;
         }
         .bigSection{
            height: 200px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="bigSection">
         <div><a name="first">First</a></div>
         <div><a href="#first">To First</a></div>
         <div><a href="#second">To Second</a></div>
         <div><a href="#third">To Third</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="bigSection">
         <div><a name="second">Second</a></div>
         <div><a href="#first">To First</a></div>
         <div><a href="#second">To Second</a></div>
         <div><a href="#third">To Third</a></div>
      </div>
      <div class="bigSection">
         <div><a name="third">Third</a></div>
         <div><a href="#first">To First</a></div>
         <div><a href="#second">To Second</a></div>
         <div><a href="#third">To Third</a></div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

## Answer using JavaScript

You need to bind an eventListener and prevent it from moving to the next page.  Here is a way to do it with JavaScript or CSS.  The JavaScript way will actually set the text to whatever you want.  The CSS way will hide actually hide the element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Link Printer</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <style>
         .hide{
            display: none;
         }
      </style>
      <script>
         function jsShowText(event) {
            var divToManip = document.getElementById("text");
            if (divToManip.innerHTML === "") {
               divToManip.innerHTML = "Hello";
            }
            else {
               divToManip.innerHTML = "";
            }
            event.preventDefault();
         }
         function cssShowText(event) {
            var divToManip = document.getElementById("text");
            if (divToManip.className === "") {
               divToManip.className = "hide";
            }
            else {
               divToManip.className = "";
            }
            event.preventDefault();
         }
         function setListeners() {
            document.getElementById("jsPrinter").addEventListener("click", jsShowText, false);
            document.getElementById("cssPrinter").addEventListener("click", cssShowText, false);
         }
         window.onload = setListeners;
      </script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div><a id="jsPrinter" href="" onclick="showText();">Click With JavaScript</a></div>
      <div><a id="cssPrinter" href="" onclick="showText();">Click With CSS</a></div>
      <div id="text">I'm text</div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Zero, I don't understand the javascript at all. I'm still very new to it still. I have a value, call it X. X gets automatically put into a link like this:

document.write('<a href="#' + x + '">  ' + x + ' </a>');

When I click on that link, I want it to display text somewhere else in the page. I'm making it just scroll to a page marker "#". How can I make it display text where its scrolling to?

Comment: @Casualty Ok, since you just want to add text after the anchor, you can do that with just CSS.  Take a look at my edit.  Will this get you what you need?

Answer (score 1):

"showText" must receive an id parameter to be used with the call to "document.getElementById"

Try this, just 1 link that will display the text below after click:

```
<a name="16:10" onclick="showText('text1')" href="javascript:void(0);">16:10</a>

<script language="JavaScript">
   function showText(id)
    {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = "block";
    }
</script>

<div id="text1" style="display:none;">This is your monitors aspect ratio.</div>
```

I'm just using style display to hide/show the element. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

just change your css like this:

```
div.show {
    display:block;
    color: #66CCFF;
}
```

Comment: Added that to the CSS. Doesn't display the text when I click on the top link.

Answer (score 0):

Here I am going to provide an example with something that I was working, thank you Alberto Montellano for the example, that gave me an idea, however what was required at the end was something a little different, with the option not to show the data and display it only when I click and make it disappear when click again. In this example I am going to give you two options; you can have a button or a link to trigger the JS function to display and hide the body text, you can choose if you want the button or link that is way I put a comment (optional), both behave as the same, it is up to you which one you want to use.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- CSS -->
<style>
#myDIV {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: lightblue;
    margin-top:20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- text before the button or link -->
<p>Click the "PIN" button (or link) to display PIN options:</p>


<!-- The Pin button (optional) -->
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">PIN button:</button>

<!-- The Pin link (optional) -->
</br></br></br>
<a onclick="myFunction()" href="javascript:void(0);">PIN link:</a>


<!--Data will display or hide (toggle)-->
<div id="myDIV"style="display:none;">
These are the steps to get your PIN number: Bla bla bla.
</div>


<p><b>Note:</b> The text display when you click the button or link will take space, if you click again will be toggle.</p>

<!-- JS -->
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDIV');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```